# Excel VBA populate array from named range

Tags: excel, vba

I need to populate an array's values with cells from a named range in another workbook. So far what I have is not working for me:

```
Dim vArray() as Variant
vArray = Workbooks("Book2").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("myRange")

Debug.Print vArray(1) 'yields error
```

Also no luck with:

```
vArray = Workbooks("Book2").Names("myRange")
```

or

```
vArray = Workbooks("Book2").Names("myRange").RefersToRange
```

Comment: Your first try is filling it correctly, you are reading it wrong though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing the print line to this:

```
Debug.Print vArray(1, 1)
```

Here is how you can loop through them:

```
Sub Test()
  Dim vArray() As Variant
  vArray = Range("myRange")

  Dim i As Long
  For i = LBound(vArray, 1) To UBound(vArray, 1)
    Debug.Print vArray(i, 1)
  Next
End Sub
```

****Edit****

To use 'Book2' without having to activate it you can do this:

```
Sub Test()
  Dim vArray() As Variant
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim wbk As Workbook

  Set wbk = Excel.Application.Workbooks("Book2.xls")
  Set rng = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("myRange")
  vArray = rng

  Dim i As Long
  For i = LBound(vArray, 1) To UBound(vArray, 1)
     Debug.Print vArray(i, 1)
  Next
 End Sub
```

---

To open book2 from another book change line 5 to this:

```
Set wbk = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Book2.xls")
```

Comment: Didn't even consider the array having 2 dimensions. This method works provided I activate Workbooks("Book2").Worksheets("Sheet1") first. I cannot create the array by pointing to Workbooks("Book2").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("myRange").

Comment: @nethy - see my edit above, I've added a couple of ways to reference Book2 without having to activate it.  Likewise, you can also get the range from Book2 without the file being opened.

Answer (score 4):

One more method.. TESTED

```
Sub Test()
Dim vArray As Range
Dim rng As Range

  With ActiveSheet
  Set vArray = .Range("myRange")
  For Each rng In vArray
  Debug.Print rng.Value
  Next rng
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This method is great in that I can point it to the other workbook without activating it first.