# How to select multiple sheets by an increasing number and print in groups in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I think my original approach is not going to work. I am able to get the code below to work and I was wondering if there is a way to get the 1 in AHU-1 to increase all the way to a number, in this case 20, and have the file name it is printing to do the same thing so the file is automatically titled. I am sorry I am really new to this software and I thought I could just copy and paste code, but its just not that simple for me.

Sub Test()
    Dim blnReplace As Boolean
    Dim sht As Object

```
blnReplace = True
For Each ws In Sheets
    If InStr(ws.Name, "FIV") And InStr(ws.Name, "AHU-1") And InStr(ws.Name, "CVB-1") Then
        ws.Select blnReplace
        blnReplace = False
    End If
Next
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="C:\USERS\USERNAME\DESKTOP\AHU-1.pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True
blnReplace = True
For Each ws In Sheets
    If InStr(ws.Name, "FIV") And InStr(ws.Name, "AHU-2") And InStr(ws.Name, "CVB-2") Then
        ws.Select blnReplace
        blnReplace = False
    End If
Next
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="C:\USERS\USERNAME\DESKTOP\AHU-2.pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

End Sub

Comment: That code unfortunately makes no sense and your question is far too vague.... Please write in more information of what you're trying to do, what your data you have in your sheet, etc. Otherwise I'm afraid you won't find much help here....

Comment: All the sheets are labeled by room number and I am trying to select them based on the room number. I understand the code doesn't make since probably why it doesn't work and why I need help. The code below works and I was trying to modify it to suit my needs.

Comment: Sub Test()
    Dim blnReplace As Boolean
    Dim sht As Object
    blnReplace = True
    For Each ws In Sheets
        If InStr(ws.Name, "sheet1") Then
            ws.Select blnReplace
            blnReplace = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Comment: Are you trying to select them all at once?

Comment: Yes, but there are other sheets with different room numbers that I don't want to select. So I just want to select sheets labeled 106, 206, 306, 406, etc.

Comment: Each sheet represents a single room number for 20 floors worth of rooms? This approach makes for a very unmanageable workbook. You may want to first rethink your approach (i.e. have the sheets represent a floor, rather than a room) before trying to fix your code.

Comment: Its a program that spits it out this way. I have no control over how the sheets are labeled. The whole workbook has about 4,000 sheets which is why I need a quicker way to select certain rooms that run up the 20 floors.

Comment: What are you going to do once you've selected all of these sheets?

Comment: Print the selection to PDF.

Comment: I edited the description because I thought I was approaching what I was trying to do the wrong way. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ThomasCocker You've changed the question completly from 'how can I select mulitple sheets and print to pdf' to 'how do I change the file name'.  Did you try my answer below or Sams' code yet pertaining to your original question?

Comment: Yes, but for my application it doesn't work thats why after seeing the responses I tried to start over with doing it a different way(not by room number, but by device name). I'm not trying to waste anyones time. It's just hard to think how to organize a 3,000 sheet excel file automatically with so many different ways to program something. I really do need help and I appreciate the answers. Does my current question sound like an easier code to write?

Comment: K, no prob, let me ask you this...What didn't work for you from mine or Sam's example?

Comment: Yours asked for the second 2 digits of the room number right? So I inputted 05, but it only printed 1 sheet with 05 in it under the name temp. I'm not too sure why it didn't print the rest of the sheets with the characters 05 in it.

Comment: So if it went by device name like the code I pasted above could it search for all sheets containing the name AHU-1 and print them under the name AHU-1 then move to finding all sheets that contain name AHU-2 and print those under name AHU-2 and so on. Sam's works, but then I couldn't figure out how to get it to print the groups separately to PDFs under each groups name, which is another reason why I revised the question to try and make it more clear.

Comment: When i Run what I pasted below it opens up the single pdf but has multiple pages for each of my sheets I specified(rooms 106,206,306, three rooms, three pages in the single pdf).  I pasted another answer that will open a separate pdf for each worksheet.

Comment: Ok I found why your code wasn't working on my sheets. It works only if 105 is the only character in the sheet name. My sheet names are long like "Women 105 FIVs". It does not find those sheets.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do an offset? Instead of offsetting a cell to the right you could offset 1 specific number up 1 each time it does an iteration then print then offset the number up 1 then print. I thought you could put in a formula to look for AHU-"i+1" if i = 0 and every time the program does an iteration "i" increases by 1. Is that possible?

Comment: I found my answer on another forum. Thanks for the help. Here is the link to that forum. http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=190560

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to first [define a Named Range](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-HA010147120.aspx) that contains all room numbers that are eligible for selection. This named range can then be [retrieved via VBA as an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038697/excel-vba-populate-array-from-named-range) and iterated over within our worksheet selection loop.

In the below example, I added a worksheet called REFERENCE to the workbook. Within this worksheet is a list of room numbers; the entire list makes up the named range `RoomNumbers`, as can be seen here:

[image]

The next step is to iterate over each worksheet (just like you were doing in your example code) and compare the current worksheet name to the eligible room numbers found in our name range. Here's some sample code to get you started:

```
Sub SelectWorksheetsWithEligibleRoomNumbers()

Dim roomIndex As Integer
Dim roomNum As Integer

'   grab valid room numbers from named range into variant array
Dim roomNumbers() As Variant
roomNumbers = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Names("RoomNumbers").RefersToRange.Value

'   loop through each worksheet in the workbook
For Each ws In Sheets
    '   loop through each room number in the RoomNumbers named range list
    For roomIndex = LBound(roomNumbers) To UBound(roomNumbers)
        '   compare the current worksheet's name again each number found
        '   in the RoomNumbers list. If the name equals an eligible room number,
        '   select the worksheet
        If InStr(ws.Name, CStr(roomNumbers(roomIndex, 1))) Then
            ws.Select False
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Here's an example of what this will accomplish:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I will try these codes and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work for you.  Although Im not sure about the efficiency of it considering your number of worksheets.

```
Sub test()

Dim RoomNum As String
Dim ws As Worksheet, flnum As Boolean

RoomNum = InputBox("Select Room Number.  (Must be in double digit form, i.e. 01,02..", "Room Number")

For Each ws In Sheets
        If ws.Name Like "*" & RoomNum Then
            ws.Select Not flnum
            flnum = True
        End If
    Next

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\temp.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
     IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

The above prints a single pdf for each sheet specified.  The below will print individual pdfs for each sheet.

```
Sub test2()

Dim RoomNum As String
Dim ws As Worksheet, flnum As Boolean

RoomNum = InputBox("Select Room Number.  (Must be in double digit form, i.e. 01,02..", "Room Number")

For Each ws In Sheets
        If ws.Name Like "*" & RoomNum Then
            ws.Select
            ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
            "C:\Room_" & ws.Name, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
             IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```