# Alternatives to Advanced Filter Combined with Subtotal and Index/Match on Large Data Set

Tags: excel, vba

The structure of the Workbook is as follow.

1. An advanced filter is ran against a long list of records (100,000's) to return like records based on criteria derived from 1 record in the list to begin with.
2. The advanced filter is numbered using subtotal to provide something to pull details of each record onto another tab for further calculations (adjustments made for differences).
3. The "as adjusted" numbers are brought back into the advanced filter tab and sorted low to high.
4. Various numbers off the non-filter tab would be wrote to a file.
5. Whole process repeats possibly 1,000's of times

Questions:

1. Any ideas to improve the execution speed of the process? I know that the bottleneck is having so many recalculations in the loop and constant rerunning of filter.
2. Any ideas to use different methods that I haven't thought about that accomplish the same thing in a more efficient or streamlined manner?

Unfortunately, I can't post the WB or a sample due to size.

```
    Sub EquityAutomated()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim StartNo As Long
    Dim EndNo As Long
    StartNo = InputBox("Enter the row on the Hsheet sheet you want the equity analysis to start on")
    EndNo = InputBox("Enter the row on the Hsheet sheet you want the equity analysis to end on")
    Dim wsProtestTest As Worksheet: Set wsProtestTest = Worksheets("ProtestTestData")
    Dim wsES As Worksheet:          Set wsES = Worksheets("EquitySpreadsheet")
    Dim wsEL As Worksheet:          Set wsEL = Worksheets("EquityList")
    Dim wsDa As Worksheet:          Set wsDa = Worksheets("Res")
    Dim subTotalsDa As Range:       Set subTotalsDa = wsDa.Range("A10:A647649")
    Dim fltrRng As Range:           Set fltrRng = wsDa.Range("A9:T647649")
    Dim fltrCritRng As Range:       Set fltrCritRng = wsDa.Range("A1:T2")
    Dim valRngDa As Range:          Set valRngDa = wsDa.Range("T10:T647649")
    Dim fullSrtRng As Range:        Set fullSrtRng = wsDa.Range("A9:S647649")
    Dim sortValRng As Range:        Set sortValRng = wsDa.Range("T9")
    Dim fullSortRngVal As Range:    Set fullSortRngVal = 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = StartNo To EndNo
        LogRng = wsProtestTest.Cells(i + 2, 1).Value2
        subTotalsDa.ClearContents
        Application.Calculate
            If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
                DoEvents
            End If
        Application.Calculation = xlManual
        fltrRng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
            CriteriaRange:=fltrCritRng, Unique:=False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.Calculate
        subTotalsDa.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=Subtotal(3,R10C2:RC[1])"
        valRngDa.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Formula = _
            "=INDEX(EquitySpreadsheet!$C$12:$GT$29,16,(MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),1)),EquitySpreadsheet!$C$12:$GS$12)+1))"
        With wsDa.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=valRngDa, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange fullSortRngVal
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .Apply
        End With
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image: Data Pull off Advanced Filter/Calc Tab]

[image: Tab with Advanced Filter/Many Records]

Comment: Thousands of times? In general, it is quicker to read from sheet to array, process in the array and then write back to sheet.

Comment: I agree, the problem is the data that is taken to the sheet is calculated upon and then returned back. My limited familiarity with an array, this can't be done. For the step 4, I agree, however this isn't really a bottleneck. The main issue is I have to run an advanced filter, take data to another tab via lookups and then do calculations on the data and then take the result back to the filter. I can't think of anyways to shortcut this process.

Comment: You can certainly perform calculations on an array if that's what you mean.

Comment: The issue is the cells are discrete, I can't group them into an array. For example, each column represents 1 row in the large data set, however each row takes an original number and posts various adjustments against it. I get the idea of writing to an array instead of to excel, however I don't think that works for the mechanic of getting the "as adjusted value" out. More of for writing the final results somewhere.

Comment: Maybe you can post a screenshot which illustrates your data and final outputs?

Comment: Added pictures of the tabs. Basically the data tab just runs an advanced filter with the criteria at the top to get the applicable rows. Then it runs a subtotal to number the returned rows. Then the data is taken to the 1st screenshot tab by referencing the top numbers in lookups. The first column is the data coming off the other file and the second column for each data point is calculations to adjust. Then the adjusted value is taken back to the advanced filter tab and sorted. This process is reran for a multitude of "subjects". Let me know if there is any additional detail I can provide.

Comment: I wonder if Excel is the best tool for this, but I'm not enough of an expert to be able to recommend anything else! That said, I think you could do all that using arrays - you'd need a few stages; the filtering could be replicated with various If conditions from which you would populate a second array. Writing back to the sheet looks like it would be slightly complicated by your irregular output. Hard to give specific advice - search online, and perhaps break your task into smaller discrete ones.

Comment: My debate is pretty much whether to try to rework it or not. It works as is now. Any ideas on tools? I need to learn more about array functions. You would use an array function instead of the advanced filter to get the returned data and then figure out a way to write it back?

Comment: No, array formulas are different and would slow your operation to a stand-still. You can maybe get an idea from the answers posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038697/excel-vba-populate-array-from-named-range

Answer (score 0):

I would actually look to using PowerQuery on this. It may be quicker, especially if you're looking to calculate new cells and put them into a table. PowerQuery is free from Microsoft and is good on anything from Excel 2010 forward (on 2016 it's known as "Get & Transform"). Calculations are written in DAX/DML. Pretty powerful and may be faster/more intuitive than the VBA solution.

Comment: I had this thought. Obviously I am biased towards tools I have used. Can I use this as the advanced filter alternative and still feed it criteria? I need to look into this more. Basically the idea would likely be. 
1. Use this as the back-end sort of deal and extract only the records I need into an ordinary excel table. 
2. Process the records the same way, however eliminating the massive filter issue will improve performance.

Can you automate the loading of the query back to excel and also the plugging in of criteria to a filter on the query based on workbook data?