# Alternative to Data Validation table, or possibly a fix for what I'm trying to do

Tags: excel, vba

**Background:**

I have a worksheet including a list of data validation tables, where we select to fill in a process train.

To limit the number of selections, I have two (2) data validation tables side by side so that you pick a Piece Class then the Piece.

The current data validation table includes the following formula for selecting (based on named ranges):

```
=IF(B35=A$1518,a,IF(B35=A$1519,b,IF(B35=A$1520,c_,IF(B35=A$1521,d,IF(B35=A$1522,e,IF(B35=A$1523,f,IF(B35=A$1524,g,IF(B35=A$1525,h,IF(B35=A$1526,i,IF(B35=A$1527,j,IF(B35=A$1528,k,IF(B35=A$1529,l,IF(B35=A$1530,m,IF(B35=A$1531,n,""))))))))))))))
```

I used named ranges such as a, b, d, so that I would use as little space as possible.

The sheet that the referenced name ranged are on is set-up like this:

```
Header1  |  Header2
Cat        Animal
Dog        Animal
Cow        Animal
Rat        Animal
Jeep       Vehicle
Car        Vehicle
```

The named ranged refer to the types of animals or cars, where the $A1518 reference, etc, is a list specifically to Animals, Vehicles, etc.

---

**Problem:**

I'm being asked to further separate the lists, which will result in twice as many named ranges.  I am currently hitting the maximum (256 character) count of the data validation table.

The resulting separation will be based on a criteria (true/false), such as:

```
=if($B$20="True",If(_old_formula_),If(_new_formula_))
```

Where the old formula is the one in the *Background* section and the new formula would have all of the new ranges I have to create.

---

**Question:**

Is there an alternative to using a data validation table in a cell, resulting in similar functionality (drop-down menu)?  After some searching, I have been unable to find an alternative.

If not, does anyone have suggestions to improve the string of if-statements I am currently using?

Where A$1518, A$1519, etc., are used, I can also make named ranges, but that will not provide enough extra space to double the amount of available ranges.

Comment: Could you use a helper sheet? So you could use one `Vlookup` instead of nested `If`

Comment: It would then be something like `If($B$20 = "True",Vlookup(B35,Helpersheet!A:C,2,0),Vlookup(B35,Helpersheet!A:C,3,0))`

Comment: @Moacir I have the named ranges on a separate sheet, so I would consider that the *helper sheet*.  Would I have the named ranges at the helper table?  Unsure if named-range "a" (range of B24:B41 on that sheet) would be listed as "a" in that lookup table.

Comment: What if you use it with `INDIRECT`? Like `If($B$20 = "True",Indirect(Vlookup(B35,Helpersheet!A:C,2,0)),Indirect(Vlookup(B35,Helpersh‌​eet!A:C,3,0)))`

Comment: I think I need to tag you, otherwise you wont get a notification, right?

Comment: @Moacir Goes to the post, so I was notified.  Company picnic was today, so just got back inside.  Let me take a look at what I can do with your suggestion.  I probably won't respond back today; meetings and the sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access .validation from VBA.  Inside the appropriate worksheet code you can add a subroutine `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)`  Set this up to monitor the initial cell change that starts the train and execute a version of the following code for every entry down the line.  You can then work off of one data worksheet.

```
    Dim ary As Variant 

    ary = Array("Value1", "Value2", "Value3") 
    'populate this array however you want.

    With ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Validation 
        .Delete 
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=Join(ary, ",") 
        .IgnoreBlank = True 
        .InCellDropdown = True 
        .InputTitle = "" 
        .ErrorTitle = "" 
        .InputMessage = "" 
        .ErrorMessage = "" 
        .ShowInput = True 
        .ShowError = True 
    End With
```

Also anyone who is going to go down this route I advise this gem.  I have not tested it but it looks promising.  http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/catchpaste.asp?AllComments=True

Comment: Thanks for this; definitely got me in the right direction.  I had been looking at .validation, but didn't think to apply the change event to work with it.  I can use my existing named ranges with this approach, and found this link which helped me work that out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038697/excel-vba-populate-array-from-named-range